# How do I make this run more than once?

Tags: java, serversocket

This code runs only once. It is for accessing a remote computer based on its ipv4 address.

I want to make it available anytime and run multiple times. What code should I add to do so and where?

```
public void run() {

    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(6609);
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("connected");
        String string = "";

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        string = in.readUTF();
        //System.out.println(string);
        ProcessBuilder pp = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe" , "/c" , "cd " + string );
        Process p = pp.start();

        DataInputStream get = new DataInputStream(p.getInputStream());

        String str = "";

        while((str = get.readLine()) != null) {
            out.writeUTF(str);
            System.out.println(str);
        }

        System.out.println("Finish server");
    } catch(Exception event) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, event);
    }
    //run();
}
```

Comment: What happens the second time? BTW, you have an empty catch(Exception) block. *Never* do that. Print out the exception, maybe it tellsyou something.

Comment: thx. i forgot that. i tested it with some code. nothing happens with the code. runs perfetly for one time. but once i use a loop. it broke. and if i use recursion, worse.

Comment: 'It broke' is not a problem description. Neither is 'the program fails'.

Comment: good answer. i wanna make it accessible at any time but this code is for once. please tell me where i should put the loop. :D

Comment: if i put a while in above the string = in.readUTF(); the program freezes. please tell me if you need all the code to solve the problem.thx in advance. :)

Comment: solved it by closing both sockets. and use run(); at the end of the function and it works. thx a lot guys. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the connection after finish server

or

if you want to run the code more than one time you can solve this problem with a lood around your read from stream

Comment: uhh yeah but the program fails..... i tried. with the loop that is. would you please tell me where should i put the loop ?

Comment: omg i did it. it works. closed both of the sockets and used recursion. and it works. thx. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

ServerSocket can only run once on the same port witout being closed.
if not you will get AWT errors,
if you really need more than one instance running on the same machine (I don't know why), 
you can try opening another serversockets in a different port.

not really elegant.